# CodeIgniter 3 Login Class Throws array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Our CodeIgniter 3 source code has an Auth class located in applications/libraries with the following function:

```
public function login($attempt) {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->load->model("users");

    // Store password entry
    $password = $attempt["password"];

    // Get user from database
    $user = $CI->users->get(array("screen_name" => $attempt["screen_name"]));

    if (!array_key_exists("password", $user)) {
        return null;
    }

    // Validate password
    $valid = crypt($password, $user["password"]) == $user["password"];
    if ($valid) {
        // Remove password - user data will be stored in session 
        unset($user["password"]);

        // If no photo uploaded, set default
        if (!isset($user["photo"]) || $user["photo"] == null) {
            $user["photo"] = "http://oururl/ourroute/assets/images/DefaultAvatar.png";
        } else {
            //$user["photo"] = "files/images/" . $user["photo"];
        }
        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

At first, I thought that the return value had to be changed from false to null  However, the error persists after changing the return value.  Since neither null nor false return values alleviate the situation, what other approach should be taken to remedy the error at hand?

Comment: The error message is your answer.`$user` is null

Comment: What authentication library is being used?

Comment: Post your `get` function. It seems you were getting an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of this line returning null, instead of an array

```
$user = $CI->users->get(array("screen_name" => $attempt["screen_name"]));
```

Before you pass $user to the array_key_exists() function, you should verify that the database returned a meaningful result.

That segment of code would be written as such

```
if ($user == null || !array_key_exists("password", $user)) {
    return null;
}
```

In doing so, you wont pass a null value to array_key_exists